# How to set value to a certain property of each object in a collection of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have class `Account` which have property :

```
publci decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

I have `List<Account> accounts` and under certain conditions I have to set the `Amount` of each `Account` to let's say zero(0). I know this may be considered as duplicate as I saw similar questions here [Traverse a Linq Expression..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624313/traverse-a-linq-expression-to-set-the-value-of-a-property-field) and here [assign value using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376405/assign-value-using-linq) but both questions are at least several years old. The first one makes more sense to me because I have respect to the people that have answered it but at the same time there were some concerns in using `SetValue` pointed by `Jon Skeet` even though `SetValue` is what I want to do in practice. The second answer "sounds" more convincing but for some reason I doubt the using of `ForEach` so I wonder what approach should I take to change the `Amount` value in my case?

Comment: Why do you *need* to use LINQ? What is wrong with a regular, boring `foreach` loop?

Comment: What is more readable than `foreach(var acc in accounts) acc.Amount = 0;`? LIN[Q] is a tool to query something not to change it.

Comment: @JeanHominal ...because ...like ...it's boring .... ? everybody that linq will not only look better, but will help you be successful in life ...

Comment: @TimSchmelter in reality you are right. But as `Noctis` maybe ironically said LINQ is modern, everybody use LINQ, your boss(or at least mine) is happy when he sees things done with LINQ so... yeah, even subjective still there are reason to use LINQ

Comment: @Leron: no boss should be happy if you provide LINQ queries with side-effects. With [Eric Lippert's words](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx): _"doing so violates the functional programming principles that all the other sequence operators are based upon. Clearly the sole purpose of a call to this method is to cause side effects. The purpose of an expression is to compute a value, not to cause a side effect."_ A query is an expression. I also agree with: _"we produce confusion, we make it harder for people to read each other’s code"_

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok, sometimes the best thing to do is not to do something. You almost convinced me in not doing this. Thanks for the good advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Interactive Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ix-Main/), they have `ForEach` operating on `IEnumerable<T>` (Ix is a "mirror" of [Rx](https://rx.codeplex.com/)), thus you can avoid calling `ToList` method (and avoid unnecessary allocations).

```
accounts.Where(a => a.Amount > 10).ForEach(a => a.Amount = 0);
```

Comment: Why should i use something else than `foreach` at all? `List.ForEach` is not better  in any case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter There's no *need*, obviously. Just some people prefer method chains. Ix has much more than `ForEach` too, it's just a tiny part of it.

Comment: Imho it is bad practice to continue a query which starts to modify something. That has side-effects which are never desired in LINQ.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `ForEach` can only be the last method in chain, so while it's not pure functional LINQ, it doesn't actually complicate anything. It's about personal preferences: functional purity vs. "nice" code.

Comment: Have a look at my comment below the question according E.Lippert's words about the principles of functional programming. It's simply less readable. Not because it is complex but because you always have to remember whether it's safe to use this method or not. Baiscally it adds nothing to a `foreach`, but it costs readability and you cannot debug it anymore.

Comment: @Athari even thugh `TimShmelter` convinced me that this is not a good idea, my question was clear and your answe is giving solution to it (the problem is not the answer but what I was planning to do) so I'm gonna accept this since it's doing what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is generally for selecting data, not mass updates.  Use foreach iterator loop and update the object, or even the [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: I'm yet to see a tangible reason for using `List.ForEach` over the `foreach` construct.

Comment: I would agree; however, it's an option and for people who like LINQ, it's more LINQ-ish than foreach.  I stick with the good old foreach iterator personally.

Answer (score -1):

```
    class Account
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        IEnumerable<Account> collection = new Account[] 
        {
            new Account() {Amount = 4},
            new Account() {Amount = 5},
            new Account() {Amount = 6},
            new Account() {Amount = 7},
        };

        Parallel.ForEach(collection, n =>
            {
                n.Amount = 0;
            });
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad, very bad advice. Not only it performs considerably worse, you're recommending usage of a method without explaining (and probably understanding) how it works.